# how to insert multiple checkbox values into a single column using java

Tags: java, mysql

java.sql.SQLException: Statement parameter 4 not set.
insert upto 3rd parameter perfectly..

My Code:

```
String values[]=request.getParameterValues("Values");
for(String category: values){
        ps.setString(3, category);
        ps.execute();
}
```

Comment: Please append the table definition and your database save code.

Comment: I think it is not possible , you redesign your tables and there will be an other containing all the values with reference of single key.

Comment: ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into Desired_job(job_seeker_id,preferred_position,preferred_job_categories, career_goals)values(?,?,?,?)");ps.setInt(1, 1237);
 ps.setString(2, djb.getPreferred_position());
 
 for(String category: djb.getPreferred_job_categories()){
  ps.setString(3, category);
  ps.execute();
  
 }
 
 ps.setString(4,djb.getCareergoals());
ps.executeUpdate();

Comment: Each iterate in `for` loop, executing statement and setting 3rd param with iterated value of category?

Comment: if i tried to insert up to 3rd param it's works fine.. didn't throw any exception. once i pass the 4th one then only it throws the exception.

Comment: Show us the code more that you tried including setting parameter and statement executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop, why are you executing after adding the category??

for(String category: djb.getPreferred_job_categories()){ ps.setString(3, category); ps.execute(); }

If your intent is to execute this query for the all the values. you should set the values and add it to a batch and finally call a single executebatch() method.

Comment: whether it is possible to insert another loop values in an another column of a same table...

Comment: Can you please be more clear on this? Are you talking about a loop inside a loop?? Please share some code snippets to understand the question